# How does this bash string manipulation work?

Tags: bash

I'm a bit confused by a bash script I'm working with. Here's a simplified bit of the syntax/operation that's confusing me:

```
STACKDIR="/Users/my.name/projects/someproject"
WORKDIR="/Users/my.name/projects/someproject/foo/bar/baz"
SUBPATH="${WORKDIR/$STACKDIR\//}"
echo $STACKDIR
echo $WORKDIR
echo $SUBPATH
```

this outputs

```
/Users/my.name/projects/someproject
/Users/my.name/projects/someproject/foo/bar/baz
foo/bar/baz
```

how does `SUBPATH="${WORKDIR/$STACKDIR\//}"` work to remove `STACKDIR` from the start of `WORKDIR`?

Comment: Check for `Pattern substitution` section in `man bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

See `${parameter/pattern/string}`

*From the link above*: The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.

The double `\\`are replaced as one `\`

Hope this helps.

*Addendum*: It's not specified by POSIX. Not all Unix shells implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It's substring replacement.

See `${string/substring/replacement}`

More to be clear:

```sh
$ string="HELLO"
$ echo ${string/"LL"/"ll"}
$ HEllO
```

More at: [Manipulating-Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#FTN.AEN6164)

Answer (score 0):

It's a substitution.

This example would clarify it

```
$ v="abc"
$ echo ${v/b/d}
adc
```